# function in $L^1\setminus L^2$

Tags: banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I'm looking for an example of a function which belongs to the Banach space $L^1$ (i.e $\int|f|< \infty$) but is not in $L^2$ (so $\int|f|^2$ is unbounded).

Does anyone know such a function?

Comment: Functions on what domain?

Comment: The examples depend on the measure space over which you integrate. And there could even be cases where no such examples exist...

Comment: The simplest domain possible

Comment: I think the simplest domain possible is $\emptyset$. Right before singletons. No examples in these cases. I guess you mean $\mathbb{R}$ with Lebesgue measure, don't you?

Comment: @juilien I meant the simplest case whert there is such an examle, indeed I was hoping for \mathbb{R} with Lebesgue measure

Comment: Then the canonical example is $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx<\infty =\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx$.

Comment: @julien Ok, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on (0,1)

Answer (score 1):

If the domain is infinite (I'll pick $(0,\infty)$), then you want a function with an integrable singularity like $x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\exp(-x)$.