# $f$ integrable but $f^2$ not integrable

Tags: measure-theory

At this point in Bartle, $X$ is a nonempty set, $\mathcal{X}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, and $\mu$ is a measure on $\mathcal{X}$.

$f\in L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$ means:

1. $f:X\to R$ is measurable.
2. $\int f^+\,d\mu<+\infty$ and  $\int f^-\,d\mu<+\infty$.
3. $\int f\,d\mu=\int f^+\,d\mu-\int f^-\,d\mu$.

Can someone share a couple of counterexamples:

1. $f\in L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$, but $f^2\not\in L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$
2. $f, g\in L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$, but $fg\not\in L(X,\mathcal{X},\mu)$

Thanks.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/408764/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our space is the reals with the Lebesgue measure.

1)Let $f(x)= n$ if $n < x < n+ \frac{1}{n^3}$, for all positive integers $n$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Thus $f(x)=n$ on an interval of length $\frac{1}{n^3}$.

Then

$$\int f =\sum \frac{n}{n^3} < \infty ,$$
$$\int f^2 =\sum \frac{n^2}{n^3} = \infty .$$

2) Take $f=g$ in the previous example.

Comment: Though you didn't say this explicitly, I believe you meant to include that $f(x) = 0$ if it is not in one of these length $1/n^3$ intervals.

Comment: @Joel Yes I did. I will add it. Thank you.

Comment: I'd like to thank folks for these extremely helpful examples. This continues to open doors for me.

Answer (score 8):

You can find another example through Calculus 2.

Take $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ on $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue Measure.

$\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} dx$ is finite.  You can compute this directly with an improper Riemann integral (that agrees with the Lebesgue integral).  However $$\int_0^1 (f(x))^2 dx = \int_0^1 x^{-1} dx$$ is divergent.

The second example you asked for can be provided through taking $f=g$ as in the other answer to this question.